# Is there a reputation limit from creating accounts on other stack exchange sites?

Tags: support, reputation, user-accounts

I just made a account on chemistry stack exchange and I got rewarded 100 reputation points on both sites because I was a well reputed member of the physics stack exchange community. And there are 170+ stack exchange sites.

So if I were too create a account on all the other 170 or so sites, will I get 17000 reputation?

Well. If this is how it works, doesn't that give me the access to almost all privileges. And if it were this easy, wouldn't spammers and other toxic people for the community take advantage and exploit this since they would have a lot of privileges?

Well. I am aware of the 200 reputation limit. I am not sure if it applies to this

Comment: Informational post on the main meta: [What is the association bonus, and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/552049)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called the "association bonus." It grants you some of the basic per-site privileges like being able to comment, based on your having been granted these privileges elsewhere on the network. The association bonus does *not* grant *all* of these privileges: for example, people who have only their association bonus can't comment on "protected" questions.

Your network-wide reputation is never really used for anything, so if you feel like making 170 accounts and never using them, go ahead. But if all you want is a big number, you could just write a big number on your hand with a marker.

Comment: well. I am not talking about myself and I am not going to make 170 accounts. I am just doubtful if all this reputation could theoretically be used wrongly.

Comment: No, because privileges are only awarded based on per-site reputation. It might be possible to make twenty accounts with reputation 1 and gain access to chat, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: I am also not talking about a network wide reputation. I also got 100 reputation in physics stack exchange. so would that give me 17000 reputation in physics stack exchange?

Comment: It would not. You can check your site privileges [here on Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), and [over at Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/privileges). Currently you have 600 rep here, and can access review queues, but on Chemistry you only have 100 rep, and can't even downvote yet. (I'm a moderator here on Physics, and I can't downvote over on Chemistry either.)

Comment: that makes stuff more clear.